# transaction log backup format sector size

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to backup a log file in SQL Server but I obtain an error message while yesterday I did it successfully. 
The only difference between yesterday and now is that I just truncate the principal table in the database.
The error message in french I get is the following:

```
USE master BACKUP LOG MQ  TO DISK = 'D:\MSSQL\BackupToSendToFtp\MQLog.bak'
```

> Impossible d'utiliser le fichier de sauvegarde
>   'D:\MSSQL\BackupToSendToFtp\MQLog.bak' car il a été formaté à
>   l'origine avec une taille de secteur de 512 et se trouve maintenant
>   sur une unité dont la taille de secteur est 4096.

Which in English should be:

> Cannot use the backup file 'D:\MSSQL\BackupToSendToFtp\MQLog.bak'
>   because it was originally formatted with sector size 522 and is now on
>   a device with sector size 4096.

A few days ago I upgraded the Azure VM to get a more powerful one. Can this be the main cause of the backup failure?

If yes then why did the backup succeed yesterday?

Comment: add the `WITH FORMAT` option to your backup command

Comment: Thanks Marx it works but as Cody said this situation could have massive performant hit

Comment: The performance hit would be from reformatting the drive itself; on the backup command this usually would only overwrite existing backups but maybe it works differently on Azure? Hopefully someone can write a better answer than me which will explain everything.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. You can't restore backups to storage with a different sector size (this is something to do with the way the log is structured internally where it would be unsafe to do so - [there's a big article on it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/b/psssql/archive/2011/01/13/sql-server-new-drives-use-4k-sector-size.aspx) which is as clear as mud).

Are you using [Storage Spaces](http://jeffgraves.me/tag/storage-spaces/)?

> The problem with all of this is that the when creating a virtual disk
>   with Storage Spaces, if you do not specify a LogicalSectorSize via the
>   Powershell cmdlet, the system will create a virtual disk with a
>   LogicalSectorSize equal to the greatest PhysicalSectorSize of any disk
>   in the pool. This means if you have SSD’s in your pool and you created
>   the virtual disk using the GUI, your virtual disk will have a 4k
>   LogicalSectorSize.

If so then you're out of luck, you can reformat the Azure disks as described to use 512 byte sectors but you'll then get a massive and permanent performance hit.

There's no way to backup/restore that database onto the new storage. You'd have to export the database schema and data from your old storage and import it to a new database on the new storage. Crazy, I know.

Comment: Tanks Cody for this interesting article!!